# CSS: Filling an image usng Keyframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

This is the image: [image: Coffee].

You know how the progress bars work, like if you give it the value of 50, and then later use javascript to change it with transition, it will be smooth, and eventually the progress bar will be filled.

Now, you see the white portion in the image?

Say, there is a field called `Votes`. Based on the value of Votes, a same amount of color should be filled inside the coffee image. (Replacing equal amount of white.)

Yes, I can develop hundred images, and do it in Photoshop, which is pretty lame.

There is a thing called keyframes, and there are animations, but I am not able to findna way to animate this using css.

I have seen it on [Behance](http://behance.net), and it is like a very common thing. The crazy thing is, I cant find it on Google.

**In simple words, based on the amount of votes, the white portion should be replaced by equal amount of some other color.**

Like this: [Codepen.io: Image Filling progress](http://codepen.io/simurai/pen/eqhEF)

Answer (score 4):

Turn the image into a transparent png, and have a colored div behind the image change height based on the number of votes.

Comment: Interesting. Let me try that. And may be if you could instantiate the code?

Comment: And what if the image has different colors, like, I mean 37.9% of the image  from the top is blue, and then a slightly skewed part of it is red, and then another 43% is lightish gray. How would you tackle that? And is it even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you - do you mean the part that is changing color based on votes, or the actual image?

Comment: If you are talking about the div that changes color - simply have 3 divs inside 1 div, and the height of those divs would be the percentage of likes/dislikes...
If you are talking about the actual image, then I'm not sure you understood me. When I say transparent png, I mean that only the white part (the cup) would be transparent, the other colors do not matter, they remain opaque

Comment: Alright. Now I understand. I will post what happens by using this.

Comment: Is there an easy tool which can convert white to transparent and vice versa?

Comment: Sorry buddy, I don't think so - open photoshop and watch a tutorial, its not complicated but it is tedious and I know I hate that stuff, but it has to be done... 
But since the last time I did that, maybe a tool appeared online so google it